# Exit Status 2 on running Grep command using Golang

Tags: bash, shell, go

I write simple script using Golang to grep a log file with some parameters. Here's my shell command

`grep CRON var/log/sys | tail -5 | grep "cd /home/raka/repo && git status"`

I want to run command above in Golang using `os/exec` package. Here's my code sniped.

````
var (
  reader io.Reader
  out    []byte
  err    error
  commandName string = "grep"
)

args := []string{"CRON", "/var/log/syslog", "| tail -6", "| grep \"git status\""}

cmd := exec.Command(commandName, args...)
r, err = cmd.StdoutPipe()
err = cmd.Start()
out, err = ioutil.ReadAll(r)
err = cmd.Wait()

return strings.Split(string(out), "\n")```
````

Currently, the sniped above doesn't work, because of `exit status 2`.
Any of you guys/ladies have solution for this problem? thank you so much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pipes (`|`) are implemented by a shell program (like bash). If you want to use them you should execute shell passing a command containing piped program invocations:

```
exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c",
    "grep CRON var/log/sys | tail -5 | grep \"cd /home/raka/repo && git status\"")
```