# How to pass a command with $() to exec.command() in golang

Tags: go

I want to execute a command like `docker exec "$(docker-compose ps -q web)" start.sh` from golang script using `exec.command()`. The problem is getting the command inside `$()` to execute.

Comment: What are you doing that doesn't work? That's a shell command, so giving to a shell should work fine.

Comment: in this particular case i get the following error ``Error response from daemon: no such id: $(docker-compose`` see what it does?

Comment: Please show the code you're using, so we don't have to guess what that is.

Comment: @Nithin that command doesn't seem to be the problem, it seems there's more here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669561/exit-status-2-on-running-grep-command-using-golang/34669821

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command inside of `$()` is executed and replaced with its output by your shell on the command line (typically `bash` but can be `sh` or others). exec.Command is running the program directly, so that replacement isn't happening. This means you need to pass that command into bash so it will interpret and execute the command:

`bash -c "docker exec \"$(docker-compose ps -q web)\" start.sh"`

Code Example:

`exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "docker exec \"$(docker-compose ps -q web)\" start.sh")`

Alternatively, you can run `docker-compose ps -q web` yourself, get its output and do the substitution instead of having bash do it for you.